# how to extract H264 video from RTP packets according to RFC 3984?

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264, rtp

I need to build receiver side of my udp video stream package to display video from my gstreamer udpsink in the browser and the only piece that is missing is extraction of h264 video from my rtp packets. I am looking for way to extract h264 from rtp packet on the fly (input - chunk from `udp` stream, output h264 data). Code receiving udp packets looks like this:

```js
const dgram = require('dgram');

// Create a UDP server
const udp_server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

// Bind the server to a port
udp_server.bind(5000);

// Handle incoming messages
udp_server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
  /* handle rtp message containing h264 video */
});
```

I've tried with NodeJS `rtp-parser` without success. The only successful way I've managed to display a video stream is gstreamer command `gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink`. I am trying to reproduce `rtph264depay` step of this pipeline

Comment: You can do this with node-gtk and an appsink element in your gstreamer pipeline. But why do this is in node.js, i.e., on the server if the goal is the browser? Shouldn't you be looking at webrtc?

Comment: @ChristianFritz the only reason to avoid WebRTC is I wanted to avoid tradeoff on quality WebRTC comes with

Comment: webrtc has absolutely no opinion on quality. It only *supports* decreasing quality (via congestion control) if necessary. But naively, if you don't enable/implement that then it will just forward your RTP stream as-is.

Comment: do you know how high level flow should look like with WebRTC included?

Comment: yes, but it's a bit involved. This gives a great overview: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling

Comment: Depending on your application you might be interested in just using the webrtc video streaming solution I've built: https://transitiverobotics.com/caps/transitive-robotics/webrtc-video

Comment: my main concern about WebRTC is that it doesn't scale and decreases quality of a video basing on factors out of my control

Comment: @szymeo _"How to extract H264 video from RTP packets..."_ What do you see after you skip the first 12 bytes of the RTP header? Is it not an H.264 **start code**? Either (A) try to print the array values of the RTP data (show us your received hex values) ...or else (B) save the packet to disk as a file and then either share the file (online link) or open it in a **hex editor** yourself to share the byte values with us for advice.

Comment: hey @VC.One here's link with rtp packet I'm receiving https://pastebin.com/3JP9q8z1

Comment: "WebRTC is that it doesn't scale and decreases quality of a video basing on factors out of my control" -- not sure what you mean by scaling, but again, no, you can easily not enable congestion control. Webrtc is not one thing it's a whole bunch of standards, some of which implement congestion control and you don't need to use all of them.

Comment: @szymeo **(1)** Is that really the **first packet** that you receive when you start outputting from GStreamer? Your shown bytes do not have any **start codes** (for each data unit _ie:_ could be metadata or a frame), and there is no bytes for the **SPS** and **PPS** metadata which is **always needed** to display a frame's picture. **(2)** I wonder if you are getting some mid-stream bytes (_ie:_ you did not connect immediately at beginning of the stream, and so you have some missing earlier packets)? Try to get the first sent packet (start port listening before GStreamer starts emitting output)

Comment: @szymeo **(3)** Make testing more quicker & easier by using a small resolution output (_eg:_ 128x28). Smaller pictures have less bytes so you can confirm a frame without needing multiple packets (and in UDP they can be out of order/sequence)...

Comment: @VC.One paste with first 3 packets I receive https://pastebin.com/s3JwaYXg

Comment: @szymeo **(1)** Your first packet is unknown to me (but I didn't think too hard about them).. **(2)** The second packet has the **SPS** that you need from offset 12 (value: `103`) until end, the third packet has the **PPS** that you need from offset 12 (value: `104`) until end of packet. **(3)** I can only assume the next packet has the keyframe so maybe check for a value of `101` at offset 12 in the next/fourth packet... Are your frame dimensions really `1552 x 1552`? Either those keyframe bytes will fit inside one packet or it will be spread out over multiple packets...

Comment: @VC.One might be that my frame dimensions are like this, I have no clue how to make them smaller. Anyway I'm looking into redistributing my UDP stream using WebRTC server like Janus or Mediasoup. Do you guys have any insights on this?

Comment: Just to add my 2 ct: having hit my head against roll-your-own video streaming solutions for the better part of a year, I finally gritted my teeth and went with WebRTC after all. Yes, the setup part with SDP and ICE is a bit iffy, but once that's in place, you get an extremely robust streaming solution, and with GStreamer, you have full control over how your media is encoded before it's fed into the WebRTC pipe.

Comment: Not sure about the implementation, but here is a good place to start:
[This](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/blob/6114c278c1616af240a78165331a761735c72664/track_local_static.go#L177) is the function that receives the UDP bytes and constructs an RTP packet.
[This](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/blob/6114c278c1616af240a78165331a761735c72664/pkg/media/h264writer/h264writer.go#L45) is the function that creates an h264 stream from the payload.

Its from Pion, a WebRTC library written in Golang. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rtp-parser package along with some custom logic. First, install the package:

```js
const dgram = require('dgram');
const RtpParser = require('rtp-parser');

// Create a UDP server
const udp_server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

// Bind the server to a port
udp_server.bind(5000);

// Initialize an empty buffer to store H.264 NAL units
let h264Buffer = Buffer.alloc(0);

// Handle incoming messages
udp_server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
  const parsedRtpPacket = RtpParser.parseRtpPacket(msg);

  if (parsedRtpPacket.payloadType === 96) { // Assuming H.264 video has a payload type of 96
    const rtpPayload = parsedRtpPacket.payload;

    // H.264 NAL unit starts with the 0x000001 or 0x00000001 prefix
    const nalPrefix = Buffer.from([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01]);

    // Concatenate the NAL prefix and RTP payload to form the H.264 data
    const nalUnit = Buffer.concat([nalPrefix, rtpPayload]);

    // Append the NAL unit to the h264Buffer
    h264Buffer = Buffer.concat([h264Buffer, nalUnit]);
  }
});

// Get the H.264 video data
function getH264Data() {
  return h264Buffer;
}
```

Only basic example but could be a good start.

Comment: I am wondering how packet sending to client side should be happening. First thought is some interval that utilises ```getH264Data``` method and passes, but maybe there's more convenient way?

Comment: @szymeo You should ask a new Question about that next topic. Your current question is about **how to extract H264 bytes** from an incoming packet/message and here you have the answer for that query.

Comment: @SolessChong The Asker mentioned in the comments that the Pastebin link has the contents of their first incoming packets: [Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/s3JwaYXg) ... There are no start codes to find. After their packet header (first 12 bytes) the H264 starts immediately with a NALU header like hex value `0x67` (or see decimal `103` as it's printed in their Pastebin).